# Sublime-like word navigation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Word navigation with <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> in Atom and Visual Studio Code is different from Sublime Text and other applications which use native word navigation.

Take the following statement, for instance:

```
c.BindJSON(&input);
```

In applications that use native word navigation, the cursor—starting at the beginning of the line—will stop before the `.`, before the `(`, before the `)`, and at the end of the line. Four total <kbd>→</kbd> strokes to navigate through the code.

When using Atom and VS Code, however, it will make two (unnecessary in most cases) extra stops: before `BindJSON` and before `input`. That results in a total of six strokes of the right arrow to navigate through the code, and makes the editor experience feel really sluggish.

This might not seem like much, but take a line that has a few word separators and code navigation starts to get terribly slow.

---

I have found the following extension for Atom, [sublime-word-navigation](https://atom.io/packages/sublime-word-navigation), which makes it behave the way I want. I could not find a similar extension for VS Code.

I was hoping someone out there could help me find it, or find something in the settings that would make it work. I have searched the settings, SO and the VS Code marketplace and could not find anything...